# RPC vs JSON comparision in GWT application

Tags: json, gwt, rpc

this is a simple but powerful question.

I have an application test which send a 1000 CustomDTO list over RPC and over REST.

I just want to get how much time it takes to deserialize the payload (in RPC) and the JSON (in REST).

My problem is that the time i get includes:

client time + server time + wire time + *deserialization time*

There is any test app or util or even a GWT util to get the deserialization time and not the other times ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Enable Lightweight Metrics in your app (http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLightweightMetrics.html)
GWT-RPC supports them out of the box, so if you will be able to see how much time each GWT-RPC request spent on serialization/deserealization

Answer (score 1):

You could override some methods of RemoteServiceServlet.
Then you could measure the time spent on serialization:

```
protected void onBeforeRequestDeserialized(String serializedRequest) {
}

protected void onAfterResponseSerialized(String serializedResponse) {
}

protected void onAfterRequestDeserialized(RPCRequest rpcRequest) {
}
```

I'm not aware of any utilities though.

Comment: is this a server class? I am interested on deserialization in client.

Comment: I don't think you can do this on the client. I mean you can parse the response but that's not serialization.
Serialization is a trick that translates your java objects to json and vice versa.
It's done in RemoteServiceServlet.
If you use GWT-RPC you'll have to create a servlet that extends this class. There you can override these methods. Also, it's importnat to keep in mind that RemoteServiceServlet zips the response.

Comment: RemoteServiceServlet does not zip the response.

Comment: It does.  See the method below in RemoteServiceServlet:
private void writeResponse(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response, String responsePayload)

Comment: it is customizable, but yes it does zip. sorry. Anyway, thankyou.